# Issue with fetching data using background script in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am working on a Chrome extension. The extension's purpose is to click on a product within a marketplace, open that product's page in an iframe, and then extract specific data using JSpath from the iframe's content.

I've encountered difficulties related to the same-origin policy. To circumvent this, I've attempted using a background script to open the product's link and retrieve the response.content. However, when I parse this content, it returns the URL of the current site instead of the one I originally sent. I'm perplexed by this behavior and am seeking insights into why this might be happening.

Additionally, I would appreciate suggestions for alternative solutions if opening iframes or using parsed DOM isn't feasible.

So basically, if I `console.log(response.content)` it gives me the correct url I sent.
If I `console.log(doc1)` it's the current URL I'm in, which is wrong and therefore it's not going correctly to my other functions.

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command: "fetchUrlContent", url: productHref}, function(response) {
                        if(response.content) {
                          console.log(response.content);
                          // Create a new DOM based on the received content
                          let parser = new DOMParser();
                          let doc1 = parser.parseFromString(response.content, "text/html");
                          // Make sure to pass this 'doc' as the document to be used for extraction
                          extractDetailPageData(extractedData.infringement, extractedData, doc1);
                          console.dir(doc1);
                          // Now you have the content, proceed with extracting data from detail selectors
                          // Here you can call the function to extract and process the data, using 'doc' as the source document
                        } else {
                          console.error('Failed to fetch content', response.error);
                        }
                      });
```